# Objective-C class to load images asynchronously

Tags: iphone, objective-c

What are the best classes with which I might asynchronously load images in Objective-C?

Comment: Load from disk, or download from server?

Comment: EGOImageLoading does a pretty good job, http://developers.enormego.com/view/what_if_images_on_the_iphone_were_as_easy_as_html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my stab at it: https://github.com/Koolistov/Image-Cache

Answer (score 1):

I found this one the best > [HJCache](http://www.markj.net/hjcache-iphone-image-cache/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading them from disk, just check out the UIImage api:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html

... for example:

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENTION ofType:@"png"]];
```

if you're loading images from the network, I like using the ASIHTTPRequest (also supports Queues) API. Check it out here:

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Answer (score 0):

How about just using NSURLConnection with an URL for the file (either a file or http URL)?